# How to make assertions based on response data in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

The scenario is:

I am making a rest call asking for access token. The token that i receive from the web service is getting passed to a subsequent rest call for validation. If the token is valid, i get **true** as response data otherwise **false**.

What i want to do is that **i want to assert based on response data. If i receive false, i want to throw an assertion.**

How can i do that in JMeter. Please suggest. Screenshot attached.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value in a variable as given below.

```
vars.put("myvar", "true or false");
```

Now in the subsequent request/assertion, use

```
${myvar}
```

---

Or, In the Beanshell post processor,

```
if(responseToken.equalsIgnoreCase("false")){
        Failure=true;
        FailureMessage="Response data not as expected";
}
```